# Can I :target parent elements?

Tags: css

I have a general purpose box. There are five smaller boxes in the middle of the main box. http://jsfiddle.net/zorikii/fKjET/

I would like the box in the middle to change background color when another box is clicked. My basic markup is as follows:

HTML-

```
<a id="101" class="select" href="#">A Question</a>
<li id="101_yes" class="one">
    <a href="#101_yes">Yes</a>
</li>
```

CSS-

```
li a:target ~ a{ background: green;}
```

The way I see it, if `li.a.href == li.id` the top level `<a>` should become selectable as a sibling of `<li>`. This does not work the way I expected.

Comment: Side note: putting an anchor in a `ul` (directly) is invalid markup

Comment: Good to know. My problem was a silly one. I just took the whole list element out and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `<li>` and use a general purpose container `<div>`:

```
<a id="101" class="select" href="#">A Question</a>
<div id="101_yes" class="one">
    <a href="#101_yes">Yes</a>
</div>
```

Comment: or use the html5-element `nav`